# mysql - multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Given these tables defitinion and relationships :

```
jobs  
tasks  
invoice_item  
invoice_payment
```

Jobs are the root of everything.
each job has multiple tasks, for example the job may be building a chair and tasks might be the steps required. Each task has a certain planned price, so buying wood for the chair can cost 400.

each task is can be billed through an invoice, invoices are stored in two tables, one table holds the invoice_id(invoice_item) while the other holds the invoice payment details like the amount to bill and to which task to bill.

There can be multiple invoices per task, so for example our task that costs 400 can have 4 invoices of 100 each.

Requirements :

Display each job in it's own row with the following information :
 1. sum of planned price for the job
 2. sum already billed for the job
 3. the job's description

I've created this sqlfiddle to provide basic data structure.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0be74
The expected result for this data set is :

```
(job_description, SUM(planned), SUM(billed))  
VALUES  
('Project A', 2000, 1900),    
('Project B', 3000, 2000)
```

My current single and only solution is failing horribly :

```
Select j.job_description, SUM(t.task_planned_price),SUM(p.invoice_amount)
FROM jobs as j
LEFT JOIN tasks as t ON t.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN invoice_item as i ON i.task_id = t.task_id
JOIN invoice_payment as p ON p.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
GROUP BY j.job_id
```

I'll deeply appreciate any guidance and some hints (or answers) as to what I'm doing wrong.
You can copy my solution directly to the sqlfiddle and see what breaks.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're joining task to invoice items and invoice payments the sum for invoice amount is incorrect because the # of task rows is multiplied by the # of invoice payment rows * invoice amount rows, you need to group these separately.

```
select j.job_description, t1.sum_task_planned_price, 
       coalesce(t2.sum_invoice_amount,0) sum_invoice_amount
from jobs j join (
    select job_id, sum(task_planned_price) sum_task_planned_price
    from tasks
    group by job_id
) t1 on t1.job_id = j.job_id
left join (
    select t.job_id, sum(p.invoice_amount) sum_invoice_amount
    from tasks t
    join invoice_item as i on i.task_id = t.task_id
    join invoice_payment as p on p.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
    group by t.job_id
) t2 on t1.job_id = t2.job_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0be74/8

Answer (score 0):

Verified working based on your sample data, tried to make it simple enough to help understand.

```
select jobs.job_id, 
       jobs.job_description, 
       sum(invoice_amount), 
       PP.PPSUM 
from   jobs, 
       tasks, 
       invoice_payment, 
       invoice_item, 
       (select job_id, sum(task_planned_price) as PPSUM from tasks group by job_id) as PP
where  jobs.job_id = tasks.job_id 
       and invoice_item.task_id = tasks.task_id 
       and invoice_payment.invoice_id = invoice_item.invoice_id 
       and PP.job_id = jobs.job_id
group by jobs.job_id
```